# Tyring to display all possible topping combinations

Tags: java, arrays, loops

- The exercise:

You’re at the ice cream store trying to decide what kind of ice cream and toppings you want. There are so many choices!

You decide to write a program to help you list out every possible choice.

Write a method

ArrayList getAllChoices(String[] flavors, String[] toppings)
That takes an array of ice cream flavors and an array of toppings as parameters, and returns an ArrayList holding every possible combination of ice cream and toppings.

Each combination should be represented in the form

```
"{{flavor}} with {{topping}} on top"
```

Where {{flavor}} is a provided flavor of ice cream, like “chocolate”, and `{{topping}} is a provided topping, like “sprinkles”.`

For example, the method call:

```
String[] flavors = {"chocolate", "vanilla"};
String[] toppings = {"sprinkles", "fudge"};
getAllChoices(flavors, toppings);
```

Should return an ArrayList holding the following Strings:

```
["chocolate with sprinkles on top", "chocolate with fudge on top", "vanilla with sprinkles on top", "vanilla with fudge on top"]
```

What I have:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllChoices(String[] flavors, String[] toppings)
{

String[] flavors = {"chocolate", "vanilla"};
String[] toppings = {"sprinkles", "fudge"};


for(int i = 0; i < flavors.size(); i ++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < toppings.size(); x++)
    {

    String flavorss = flavors[i];
    String toppingss = toppings[x];

    return (flavorss + " with " + toppingss + " on top");




    }
}   


}
```

Not very good at this and not sure why it isn't working.

Edit: Got it using this solution.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllChoices(String[] flavors, String[] toppings)
{
    ArrayList<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i ++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < toppings.length; x++)
        {

            String flavorss = flavors[i];
            String toppingss = toppings[x];

            // Add to list instead of returning.
            retList.add(flavorss + " with " + toppingss + " on top");
        }
    }

    return retList;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I may have gone a bit funny in the head, but isn't this C#?

Comment: Yes, this is C# :P
Remember when a function hits a return statement, it terminates and returns what you tell it to. Here you're returning the very first statement ("chocolate with sprinkles on top") without ever executing more. You want to create an ArrayList<String> and add each combination to that before returning that ArrayList.

Comment: Please read [ask]. While a homework question can be a good question, you need to [edit] into one rather than copying and pasting it into the question field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `Java` and `JavaScript` its two other languages. I guess you would like to write this program in `Java`, your function should return `ArrayList<String>` as you declare here:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllChoices(String[] flavors, String[] toppings){...}
```

so you should create temporary `ArrayList` and add all your strings, that you create to the list, and after (out of loops) you should return it, if u do something like this (even if it work):

```
return (flavorss + " with " + toppingss + " on top");
```

your function will exit after one iterate of nested loops, what else `return` type isn't a `ArrayList<String>`, it is just `String`.

Here is a solution how you can handle this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllChoices(String[] flavors, String[] toppings) {
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < toppings.length; x++) {
            String temp = flavors[i] + " with " + toppings[i] + " on top";
            tempList.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

PS. There is no `size` method of the `array`, you should use `length` instead.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllChoices(String[] flavors, String[] toppings)
{
    ArrayList<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i ++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < toppings.length; x++)
        {

            String flavorss = flavors[i];
            String toppingss = toppings[x];

            // Add to list instead of returning.
            retList.add(flavorss + " with " + toppingss + " on top");
        }
    }

    return retList;
}
```

Your iteration was fine, but you were returning the list too early.  Your execution would only return the first result.

Also, this is java syntax.  not javascript.

Comment: I tried doing the arraylist first and returning after. When I do it this way I get a weird error.

Grader.java: Line 10: You may have forgotten to declare size() or it's out of scope.

Comment: ArrayList length is provided with the .size() method.  Array length (like flavors and toppings are) is .length.  I'll edited the response for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the language and the tag mismatch, the error is the immediate return inside of the two nested loops. you should first collect results in an array and then return it.